# How to get entity id of newly created entity using entity_get_controller

Tags: 7, entities

I am crating the new entity in drupal a below,

```
$entity = new stdClass();
$entity->type = 'entity_type';
$entity->id = 0;
$entity->title = 'Entity Title';

//Add data to fields
$entity->field_introduction = array
            (
                'und' => array
                (
                    "0" => array
                    (
                        'value' => $strIntroduction
                    )
                )
            );

     .
     .
     .
     .


    //After adding all the fields, I am saving entity as follows,

entity_get_controller('summary_report')->save($entity);
```

Entity get saved successfully. After this I want entity id for the further manipulations. 
How I get this newly created entity id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `id` is the name of your ID entity key, use this after the save:

```
$id = $entity->id;
```

You also have the option of using [`entity_extract_keys`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_extract_ids/7.x) if you want to do it more generically:

```
list($id, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);
```